# Ingresar solo numeros

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

quisiera saber como puedo en un `QTextEdit` permitir solo el ingreso de números, hay alguna propiedad para ello?
PD: necesito que no deje escribir o ingresar en el `QTextEdit` letras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes optar por heredar de QTextEdit y sobreescribir el método `event` o bien puedes instalar un filtro de eventos.

Para hacer uso de un filtro de eventos necesitas un objeto que herede de `QObject`... puede ser la propia ventana que contiene el `QTextArea` o una clase independiente, eso al gusto. Lo verdaderamente importante es que la clase en cuestión implemente el método `eventFilter`. Este método recibe dos argumentos:

- Objeto que lanza el evento
- Evento lanzado

Y la función debe retornar `true` o `false` en función de si desea *desactivar* o no el evento (se puede desactivar para anular el evento o simplemente porque ya se ha tratado el evento y no se desea el comportamiento estándar).

Suponiendo que sea la propia ventana la que implementa la función, el sistema podría quedar así:

**NOTA**: Este ejemplo asume que el objeto `QTextArea` se llama `textArea`.

**MainWindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    bool eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event) override;

  private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

**mainWindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  // Instalamos el filtro de eventos
  ui->textEdit->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event)
{
  if( ui->textEdit == object )
  {
    if ( event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress )
    {
      auto keyPress = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
      switch( keyPress->key() )
      {
        // numeros
        case Qt::Key_0:
        case Qt::Key_1:
        case Qt::Key_2:
        case Qt::Key_3:
        case Qt::Key_4:
        case Qt::Key_5:
        case Qt::Key_6:
        case Qt::Key_7:
        case Qt::Key_8:
        case Qt::Key_9:

        // tecla de borrar (backspace)
        case Qt::Key_Back:

        // tecla suprimir
        case Qt::Key_Delete: 

        // cursor
        case Qt::Key_Left:  
        case Qt::Key_Right:
        case Qt::Key_Up:
        case Qt::Key_Down:
          break; // A estas teclas se les da el tratamiento por defecto

        default:
          return true; // se desactivan todas las demás
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Y ya está, no hay que nacer nada más. Si pruebas el ejemplo verás que el control únicamente va a admitir dígitos numéricos.

Comment: muchas gracias, me ah servido de mucho ;)